# Magento 2.4.2 Contact Us Page gives 502 Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I am using Claue theme magento 2.4.2 with custom page (default) provided by claue theme. Code i was using is given below:

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

But whenever I open the page in browser I get 502 error and php-fpm user for magento exits. If i remove the `template` from the above code, then it works fine without any error. I am not sure what's causing the error.

But yes, before this error, what I did was installed module `https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect`, but even though I have now removed it. I am still getting the error. I then deleted the directory root and restored the directory from previous backup, but its still the same.

I am not sure if some data was changed in the database. Any help?

**EDIT:**

I also removed the redis cache but its still the same.

Answer (score 2):

5xx error is from server, you can read the `var/log` and `var/report` folders to get the error messages. This is much better for debugging than just the http status code.